# Vue-CLI and Visual Studio Code formatting conflicts

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I generated a Vue.js project using this tutorial: https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/real-world-vue-js/vue-cli/

And then I proceeded to change `Visual Studio Code` settings and project configuration as described here: https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/real-world-vue-js/optimizing-your-editor

Unfortunately, this caused the `Vue-CLI` and Visual Studio Code to have different formatting settings. Whenever I save a file in `VS Code`, it gets formatted (which is fine). But when I run a command in `Vue-CLI`, all the files get reformatted by different rules. This means that almost all the files get modified even if the change is irrelevant to what I'm doing. This is driving me crazy.

How can I get these tools "in sync" so that they don't apply different formatting rules? Which configuration files are relevant for this?

Or would it be possible do disable the formatting in `Vue-CLI` completely?

**UPDATE:**

Recently I noticed that `VS Code` is messing up the formatting by itself. Even without using `Vue-CLI`. When I make changes to a `.vue` file and save them, `VS Code` adds trailing commas after last elements in javascript maps. When I make a couple of additional changes, the commas stay there. But then with another change, it suddenly removes them all. This behavior seems completely random.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called `prettierrc.js` in the root directory with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingComma: "all",
  arrowParens: "always",
};
```